# Replace several substrings to several substrings in single string using vba (excel)

Tags: regex, excel, string, vba, replace

please tell me whether it is possible to perform a replacement in a string that combines several different substitutions using VBA (excel)?

For example:

```
text = Replace(text, find1, res1)
text = Replace(text, find2, res2)
```

Real example:

```
text = Replace(text, "&nbsp;", " ")
text = Replace(text, "&amp;", "&")
text = Replace(text, "&lt", "<")
```

Maybe regexp?

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly like your examples show -- use three statements. Unless there are more details that you left out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest them:

```
Text = Replace(Replace(Replace(Text, "&nbsp;", " "), "&amp;", "&"), "&lt", "<")
```